# How to open multiple Incognito tabs with Python's Webbrowser Module?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to write a script that will open multiple incognito tabs in the same window. However, the websites seem to open in separate windows and I'm not sure how to get this to work.

I've already tried `webbrowser.open_new_tab()` and it opens the websites in their own windows instead of in a single window.

```
import webbrowser

incognitoPath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito"

controller = webbrowser.get(incognitoPath)

controller.open("www.twitch.com")
controller.open("www.youtube.com")
```

The behavior of the script currently is that it opens an incognito tab with the first website and then when that window is closed, it opens another window for the second website.

I want the script to open only one incognito window with all the websites in separate tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the new option in open?

```
import webbrowser

incognitoPath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito"

controller = webbrowser.get(incognitoPath)

controller.open("www.twitch.com")
controller.open("www.youtube.com", new=2)
```

Comment: Yes I have, however it doesn't change the behavior of the script.